# PHP functions variables scope

Tags: php

Say I have...

```
function one($x){
     return $a + $x;
}

function two(){
     $a = 5;
     echo one(3);
}
```

Will this show the answer "8" or "3"? In other words, will function one get the value of $a or do I need to declare it global somewhere?

N.B. I haven't tried it yet, but I'm asking it here to understand WHY it acts one way or the other.

Comment: Instead of using `global` you should pass it as a parameter, if you get to the point where your function needs lots of parameters then you should build a class, then all property's are available to that method. Dont make your code ugly!!!

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Can you give an example of using a class with my example (because I effectively have about 20 variables to pass)?

Comment: That's a bit broad, as it goes back to basic questions about software design and can hardly be answered with one example. Start with similar questions like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861163/php-function-design-passing-parameters

Comment: @deceze Considering all this, a simple if/else with the functions would do the job instead of messing around with variables. However, would a syntax of classes/functions be optimal in terms of performance over if/else structure ?

Comment: Performance is entirely secondary. Grouping code into functions, classes and files first and foremost serves to make it maintainable and logical. That's why you're writing PHP instead of Assembler. Your program is *not* going to see a significant drop in performance from an extra function call or two.

Comment: @deceze In my case, it is a loop executing 1000 times one of 30 possible events. And that loop is executed about 200 times each hour (it is for a simulation game actually). So performance comes in account when that script runs for 4-5 mins each time. In that case, will functions or if/else structure work best?

Comment: *Benchmark it!* A function call adds a few processor cycles to the execution time. This is not something you will ever notice. Calling a function that does *nothing* a few million times won't even make a blip on the CPU. The function call is not what makes a program slow!

Comment: @deceze well, it is quite a task (the entire code, broken down, makes about 2500 lines) so I want to avoid losing that time if there is a "best way" of doing things, but you seem to be saying that either way will be as resourceful. I'll opt for a "switch" in that case I guess... I though functions were better since PHP doesn't have to go through all the code each time, evaluating conditions ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No function `one` does not know about `$a`. But this can be done.

```
$a = 5;

function one($x){
 global $a;
 return $a + $x;
}

function two(){
 global $a;
 $a = 5;
 echo one(3);
}
```

Now `two()` would echo `8`

Comment: Using `global` scope is of course not what you usually want to do. Limited function scope is a *feature* that works to your advantage, not something that needs to be "worked around" by using `global`.

Comment: @Broncha My variable $a needs to be declared in function two..how would I do it?

Comment: This is just the answer to the question. He asked if what he has is possible, and I answered that this would be possible for what he asked for. Other way to do this is OOP and define class variables and member methods..

Comment: @Adam Pass it as a parameter into `one()`. If the function `one` needs that value to do its job, then it should be an explicit parameter.

Comment: @AdamStrudwick yes you define your variable in function `two` and call functino `one` with both the parameters

Comment: @Adam Think of a function as a standalone piece of code. If you copy-pasted it into a file of its own, it should work just like that. If you create a dependency of the function to some `global` variables, you're very quickly going to be writing unmaintainable spaghetti code.

Comment: @deceze So if I effectively have a dependency, what is the best alternative (instead of passing 20 variables through the function)?

Comment: @Adam Create a new question about that or, better, search for existing ones. You're not the first to face that problem about general software design. :)

Comment: @AdamStrudwick OOP is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Functions do not inherent scope from the function that calls them. (Nor do they inherit global variables by default - that's what the `global` keyword is for.)

Thus, `$a` will be completely undefined inside of `one()` and you'll get a notice about it.

For more details, see the [Variable Scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) page in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get `8` or `3`. You'll get a Notice since `$a` has not been defined in the scope of the function `one`, and you attempt to read it:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: a in - on line 3
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() -:0
PHP   2. two() -:11
PHP   3. one() -:8
```

Answer (score 1):

If you to use a class as close as to your example, Notice no global usage, just assign your variables `$this->*` then there global scope within the class and its methods/functions you can also access them  from outside of the class like `$functions->a`:

```
<?php 
Class functions{

    function one($x){
        return $this->a + $x;
    }

    function two(){
        $this->a = 5;
        echo $this->one(3);
    }

}

$functions  = new functions();

$functions->two(); //8

echo $functions->a;//5
?>
```